# Converting a wav from Stereo to Mono in Node?

Tags: node.js, audio, wav

Given a standard 16000 sample rate wav file in stereo, I'd like to convert it to mono in NodeJS. Python has PyDub; is there anything similar for Node? If not, how would it be accomplished?

Comment: must you use node or will a command line tool work ?

Comment: Node would be preferred